# Submenu toggles, top level link does not work

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, menu, navigation

I'm having an issue with my mobile menu and submenu.

On mobile view, when clicking the top-level link, my sub-menu toggles open to show the sub-links but now the sub-links do not work and the top level link does not work (it does not go to its URL).

Unfortunately, I cannot manually overwrite the HTML menu structure so I tried adding a caret link (using JQuery) to make the submenu appear when clicking a caret. But, it did not work. Maybe, I could append or prepend a button link (with JQuery) to the left side of the top level menu item (li) to make that a button or caret which toggles the submenu while still allowing the top level link to go to its URL. I hope that explains it all well. I appreciate any help. Thank you.

/**HTML**/

```
<#nav id="nav">
    <li id="menu-item-8000" class="menu-item menu-item-has-children menu-item-8000"><a href="https://website.com/home/visit/" class="open-submenu">Visit</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: block;">
        <li id="menu-item-7891" class="menu-item menu-item-7891"><a href="https://website.com/home/visit/sublink-one/" class="open-submenu">Visit Sublink One</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-7892" class="menu-item menu-item-7892"><a href="https://website.com/home/visit/sublink-two/" class="open-submenu">Visit Sublink Two</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-7893" class="menu-item menu-item-7893"><a href="https://website.com/home/visit/sublink-three/" class="open-submenu">Visit Sublink Three</a></li>
      </ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-8001" class="menu-item menu-item-has-children menu-item-8000"><a href="https://website.com/home/events/" class="open-submenu">Events</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: block;">
        <li id="menu-item-7894" class="menu-item menu-item-7891"><a href="https://website.com/home/events/sublink-one/" class="open-submenu">Events Sublink One</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-7895" class="menu-item menu-item-7892"><a href="https://website.com/home/events/sublink-two/" class="open-submenu">Events Sublink Two</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-7896" class="menu-item menu-item-7893"><a href="https://website.com/home/events/sublink-three/" class="open-submenu">Events Sublink Three</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
</nav>
```

/**JQuery**/

```
//Add caret to top level mobile menu item
  $(document).ready(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 960) {
  $('#nav li>:not(ul)').addClass('open-submenu');
    }
 });

/* This is used to show the sub-nav on mobile */
$(function(){
   $('.open-submenu').on('click', function(e){
       if(Modernizr.mq('screen and (max-width:767px)')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next($('.sub-menu')).slideToggle();
       }
   })

});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly

```
$(function() {

    var isNotMobile = $(window).width() > 786;

    $('.menu-item').each(function() {

        var item = $(this);
        var button = $('.open-submenu', item);
        var subMenu = $('.sub-menu', item);

        button.on('click', function(event) {
            if (isNotMobile) return true;
            event.preventDefault();
            subMenu.slideToogle();
            return false;
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, Dmitrii.

I was trying to create a standard mobile menu like this: With top links on the left (which leads to a URLs of Home, About, Visit, or Events) and a caret, or down arrow, on the right which opens up the submenu under each of those top links.


Home        V
About        V
Visit           V
Events       V

Here is a visual example of what I was trying to create:
https://media.nngroup.com/media/editor/2017/06/15/cupertino.png

Comment: I figured a way to add a button that opens a submenu without affecting the top level item link.

The only small issue I have now is that clicking the button opens all the submenus under all the top level links. I'm thinking using '.this' somewhere within my code would work?

    //Add button to all top level links that have a submenu
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sub-menu').before($('<button class="submenu-button">Test</button>'));

$('.sub-menu').hide();

$(".submenu-button").click(function(){

$(".sub-menu").slideToggle();
});

});

Comment: Hi. To be honest it's not easy to help you without see the all code. You could text me in Skype (pantyuhind) and I try to help you with you'r issue.

Comment: I appreciate that, but I just solved my issue and posted the solution. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my submenu issue with lots of trial and error. The solution was quite simple, but it's been a while since I coded JQuery. I hope this helps someone else with a similar code issue:

```
/** HTML **/
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://website-page-1.com">Top Level Link</a>
   <!-- Insert button here to toggle submenu -->
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="http://website-page-2.com">Top Level Link</a>
   <!-- Insert button here to toggle submenu -->
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

/** JQuery **/
//Add button to all top level links that have a submenu
  $(document).ready(function () {
   if ($(window).width() < 960) {
  $('.sub-menu').before($('<button class="submenu-button"></button>'));

  $('.sub-menu').hide();

  $('.submenu-button').click(function () {
    $(this).next('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
   });
  }
});
```

/** CSS **/

```
.submenu-button {
   width: 60px;
   height: 54px;
   background-color: transparent;
   border: 0;
   text-align: center;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   z-index: 9999;
   font-weight: 700;
}

.submenu-button:after {
    color: #fff;
    content: ' ▾';
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }

}
```